# Nested Classes C#

Tags: c#, nested

I have data that looks like this:

Series1
Image1 ImageFile1
Image2 ImageFile2
Image3 ImageFile3

Series2
Image1 ImageFile1
Image2 ImageFile2
Image3 ImageFile3
Image4 ImageFile4

Series3
Image1 ImageFile1

I was trying to store it using Lists and this class:

```
  private List<SeriesClass> dcm = new List<SeriesClass>();

   public class SeriesClass
    {

      public int SeriesId { get; set; }
      public int Value1 { get; set; }
      public string Value2 { get; set; }

    }
  Loop that populates the data {
   dcm.Add(new SeriesClass { Value1 = value1, Value2 = value2, SeriesId = seriesnum});
}
```

Obviously not including all the code. My result is something that looks like this:

Series1 Image1 ImageFile1
Series1 Image2 ImageFile2
Series1 Image3 ImageFile3

Series2 Image1 ImageFile1
Series2 Image2 ImageFile2
Series2 Image3 ImageFile3
Series2 Image4 ImageFile4

Series3 Image1 ImageFile1

I was wondering if there is a good way to nest the classes so that SeriesID becomes like a keyfield containing the rest of the data. Like I can pull up a list of the Images under a particular Series.

I tried to do this:

```
public class SeriesClass
        {

      public int SeriesId { get; set; }

public class ImageClass{
      public int Value1 { get; set; }
      public string Value2 { get; set; }
          }

         }
  Loop that populates the data {
      dcm.Add(new SeriesClass { SeriesClass.ImageClass.Value1 = value1, SeriesClass.ImageClass. Value2 = value2, SeriesClass.SeriesId = seriesnum});
}
```

But the List.Add thing doesn't allow that.. Any help would be appreciated. I just started working with C# yesterday so this is kinda new for me. If there is a better way to do this with jagged arrays or Dictionary or something I'd be up for that too.

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please edit the question so it shows where the output is coming from? As it stands this question is very unclear because we have no way of knowing about the most important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use a Dictionary.
Dictionary can use the id as a key and a list as values.

```
   private Dictionary<Integer,List<SeriesClass>> dict= new Dictionary<Integer,List<SeriesClass>>();

   public class SeriesClass
    {

      public int Value1 { get; set; }
      public string Value2 { get; set; }

    }
  Loop that populates the data {
   if ( dict.containsKey(seriesNum) ){
       dict[seriesNum].Add(new SeriesClass { Value1 = value1, Value2 = value2});
   }else{
      var list = new List<SeriesClass>();
      list.Add(new SeriesClass { Value1 = value1, Value2 = value2} );
      dcm.Add(seriesNum, list);
   }
}
```

I havent tested the code so there might be syntax mistakes but I hope you get the gist. TryGet might be better instead of using containsKey.

Comment: Quick response! Very interesting, I didnt know you could search for specific id with dictionary. Will try it out! thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome.. works very well just had to fix the typo at the end dcm=dict. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Osama Javed.